# how do the site recognise me after changing ip and clearing cache ??? how it works?

Tags: c#, vb.net, web

On certain sites we are allowed to download a limited amount of data per day.

After changing my IP address, clearing cache and resetting the Modem still they recognize me.

What data are they saving on their servers? How do they still recognize me?

Comment: did you clear cookies?

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `C#` and `vb.net`?

Comment: search term: "supercookie http".

Comment: @jim yes. they recognise me so perfectly that i wonder what actually they do ???

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of methods for identifying a remote user.  The most common and most reliable is a simple cookie containing a session ID or some other identifier.  Chances are, you didn't clear your cookies when you cleared your cache.

Other methods include HTML5 [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), and URLs specific to you (did you save a favorite/bookmark for a page with an ID in it?).

On the shady side, sometimes font detection, browser plugins, and other fingerprinting can be used to identify a browser.  This is not a perfect solution as there are certainly collisions, but you might be surprised how unique your browser configuration is.  See also:  https://panopticlick.eff.org/

In practice, sites often use a combination of information for limiting downloads and what not.  One limit for unique cookies, another for per IP address, etc.

Comment: Thanx for such nice info. It brought me to 1 from zero. Actually i am thinking about my final year project which will use some tricks like this using C#.

Answer (score 1):

> After changing my IP

My bet is; you didn't. Your IP is provided by your ISP. Resetting you modem is usually not enough to get a new address.

Try a site like http://www.myip.nl to check if your "out doors" IP is really changed.

Comment: i think this is correct

Comment: By changin ip i mean i used proxy. Reseting modem was just a try that may be it work,because our ISP gives us dynamic ips.